# ParseTwitterUtils Internal Server Error

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, parse-platform, parse-server

I just finished up movie my app over to Parse Server. I've got everything working except for my Twitter Login and Signup. When I login or signup, I get an Internal Server Error message printed to my console. I am using the latest Parse SDK. Here is my login code (my signup code is similar, it just gets other data from the Twitter API and stores it to my database):

```
PFTwitterUtils.logInWithBlock {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if let user = user {

                if user.isNew {

                    spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

                    PFUser.currentUser()?.deleteInBackground()

                    self.displayNoticeWithTwoActions("Account Not Found", message: "This Twitter account is not in our system. You have to sign up first.", firstButtonTitle: "Sign Up", closeButtonTitle: "Ok", segue: "dontHaveAccountSegue")


                } else if error != nil {

                   spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)

                    self.displayError("Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)

                } else {

                    spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("successfulLoginSegue", sender: self)

                }


            } else {

                spinningActivity.hideAnimated(true)


                self.displayError("Error", message: "Unless you tapped on 'Cancel' or 'Done', something went wrong. Please try again.")

            }
        }
```

The only thing I could find online is that it could be a problem on Twitter's end...I made sure my consumer key and secret were right in my AppDelegate. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll have to add your Twitter auth key to your parse server config file

Comment: In my case, I use the Parse Server on Heroku. Does this mean that I would add a key, TWITTER_AUTH, to the list of keys? Is it recommended that I add my Facebook key to the list? The Facebook login and signup works without the key listed on the server. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your `index.js` file that is your config file for Parse Server, you'll need to add this:

```
var api = new ParseServer ({
    databaseURI: xxxxxxx,
    cloud: xxxxxx,
    appID: xxxxxx,
    //more keys
    //add oauth keys
    oauth: {
         facebook: {
             appIds: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
         },
         twitter: {
             appIds: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
         }
   }
})
```

Comment: I do t have an index.js file because I'm hosting the server on Heroku. I have the option to add keys in Heroku, however. Do you know what the key name is for Facebook and Twitter? Would I just do "Key" = Facebook and "Value" = appId as well as "Key" = Twitter and "Value" = consumerKey?

Comment: You can clone your project from Heroku with their command line tools, modify the index.js file, and then push the changes back to Heroku.

Comment: Check the links here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command and here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#push-local-changes